# How do I find the power of this circuit?

Tags: power, circuit-analysis

This is a circuit from one of my texts:

[image]

according to the text power in I<sub>1</sub> = -12 watts, R<sub>1</sub> = +40 watts and V<sub>1</sub> = -28 watts.

My take on the circuit:

I'm assuming since current from the current source is flowing into R<sub>1</sub> I can just do P=I<sup>2</sup>/R to get the power at R<sub>1</sub> and for the power at V<sub>1</sub> I do P=I*V but I don't get how to find I<sub>1</sub> without taking power at V<sub>1</sub> and subtracting power at R<sub>1</sub>. Is that the only way to do it?
also is my assumptions right to get the answers the text got?

Comment: You cannot calculate the power consumed by a current source.

Comment: The power dissipated in R1 is I squared _times_ R.  I1 is given as 2 amps.

Comment: @Andyaka: What's wrong with calculating the voltage across a current source and finding P = IV?

Comment: @Gregd'Eon I always think of current sources as being infinite voltage sources in series with infinite resistance where the two infinities are ratioed to create the finite current. But I basically misread the question as to what power was needed.

Comment: Sure, but it's not that hard to find that there's 6 V across this current source

Comment: Yeah it's easy providing I didn't misread the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The voltage across the resistor is

$$V_{R1} = 2\mathrm A \cdot 10 \Omega  = 20V$$

with the more positive terminal on the left (since the current from the current source *enters* the left-most resistor terminal.

Thus, the voltage across the current source (being careful to choose the reference direction such that the current *enters* the positive labelled terminal per the [passive sign convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_sign_convention)) is, by KVL:

$$V_{I1} = (V_{V1} - V_{R1})\mathrm V = (14 - 20)\mathrm V = -6\mathrm V$$

The power associated with the current source is then

$$P_{I1} = V_{I1} \cdot I_{I1} = -6\mathrm V \cdot 2\mathrm A = -12\mathrm W$$

By the passive sign convention, when the power is negative, the circuit element is *supplying* power to the circuit thus, the current source **supplies** \$12 \mathrm W\$ of power to the circuit.

As a check, the sum of the powers should be zero.

The power delivered to the resistor is:

$$P_{R1} = 20 \mathrm V \cdot 2 \mathrm A = 40 \mathrm W$$

The power associated with the voltage source is

$$P_{V1} = -14 \mathrm V \cdot 2 \mathrm A = -28 \mathrm W$$

The sum of the powers is then

$$P_{I1} + P_{R1} + P_{V_1} = (-12 +40 -28) \mathrm W = 0 \mathrm W$$

as required.

Note that another approach would be to calculate the resistor and voltage source powers using the series current and write, using the fact that the sum of powers is zero:

$$P_{I1} = -(P_{R1} + P_{V1}) =  -\left((2\mathrm A)^2 \cdot 10 \Omega - 14\mathrm V \cdot 2\mathrm A)\right) = -12\mathrm W$$

as before.

Answer (score 0):

\$I_1\$ is an independent current source, this means that the current in the circuit is forced by that source to be \$2A\$ in clockwise direction. This means that the voltage across the current source is given by the voltage drop across \$R_1\$ (\$ 10\Omega \times 2A = 20V\$) minus the voltage provided by the voltage source (they are in opposite directions), so the voltage across the current source is \$6V\$ (with the upper terminal at higher potential). Therefore the power put out by the current source is \$ 6V x 2A = 12W \$, and so it *absorbs* \$-12W\$.

The power absorbed by the resistor is \$10\Omega \times (2A)^2 = 40W\$, whereas the power put out by the voltage source is \$2A \times 14V = 28W\$ hence it *absorbs* \$-28W\$.